# Find a circular dependency in a collection c#

Tags: c#, .net

I've a collection of `DataItem` class.

**DataItem :** `Property` `RefItem` stores ref to a `DataItem` that could be same collection.

```
public class DataItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DataItem RefItem { get; set; }
}
```

**Collection:**

```
 private List<DataItem> dataitems;

    public List<DataItem> DataItems
    {
        get { return dataitems; }
        set { dataitems = value; }
    }
```

Now I have two methods for adding data in the collection and validating data in collection.

```
 public void AddItem(DataItem item)
    {
        DataItems.Add(item);
    }

    public bool ValidateDataItems()
    {
        //Logic for circular reference
        //
        return true;
    }
```

I want a algorithm in validate method to check if there is any circular dependency in my collection.For ex. Below is an invalid data for me. As item3 is again pointed by item1.

```
       var item1 = new DataItem() {ID=1,Name="First Item",RefItem =null};
        var item2 = new DataItem() { ID = 1, Name = "First Item", RefItem = item1 };
        var item3 = new DataItem() { ID = 1, Name = "First Item", RefItem = item2 };
        item1.RefItem = item3;
        AddItem(item1);
        AddItem(item2);
        AddItem(item3);
```

If items are added to collection like Item1->item2,item2-> item3,item3->item1 or any other possible combination of where a ref item of a class is pointing back. I want validation method to return false.

It's a circular dependency problem but I couldn't find any concrete algorithm to do so in c#.

Comment: Couldn't you traverse all references, keeping track of existing references? If a new reference if one you've already encountered, it's circular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this [solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YGrhWk):

```
public class DataItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DataItem RefItem { get; set; }
}    

public class Checker
{
    public static bool Check(DataItem item)
    {
        var chain = new Dictionary<DataItem, DataItem>();
        chain.Add(item, null);
        try
        {
            ProcessNodes(chain, item);
            return true;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static void ProcessNodes(Dictionary<DataItem, DataItem> chain, DataItem item)
    {
        if (item.RefItem != null)
        {                
            chain.Add(item.RefItem, null);
            ProcessNodes(chain, item.RefItem);
        }
    }

    public static bool ValidateDataItems(List<DataItem> items)
    {
        foreach(var item in items)
            if(!Check(item))
                return false;
        return true;                
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var item1 = new DataItem() { ID = 1, Name = "First Item", RefItem = null };
    var item2 = new DataItem() { ID = 1, Name = "First Item", RefItem = item1 };
    var item3 = new DataItem() { ID = 1, Name = "First Item", RefItem = item2 };
    item1.RefItem = item3;

    Console.WriteLine(Checker.Check(item1));
    item1.RefItem = null;
    Console.WriteLine(Checker.Check(item1));

    //Sample how to check all existing items    
    Console.WriteLine(Checker.ValidateDataItems(new List<DataItem>{item1, item2, item3}) ? "items is OK" : "One or more items have dependency");        
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. But I can't restrict a user from adding items in the collection, I'll just have to show some validation  message if above happens. Think it like a have a collection already and now I just have to validate it.

Comment: Also if in a list of items are not connected by ref then I'll have to call Check method again n again. And since I can't make that decision while compile time I'll just have to call it for every item.

Comment: @KyloRen then instead of throwing the exception put up your validation message. It's typically better to not corrupt the collection then spend time checking it after the fact.

Comment: Answering to first comment:when you add new item to collection just not check it. Then you can iterate throughout the list and check each of items on recursive dependency and on first existence `return true` otherwise `false`. You can perform it at **any time**. I not fully understand second comment: you asked what about if one of dependent items was passed not by reference but as copy of item, can you explain more clearly?

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov 2nd comment meant, your logic use the RefItem property  to navigate further in items , But that can't make sure of if all items are processed, as some RefItem values can be null.

Comment: @kenny I don't have control over this collection I got it from another layer. and RefItem property is used for some business logic to it is not restricted to have circular ref. I just need to ward the user.

Comment: Can you post example of items which interest you at context of second comment?

Comment: I think, I understand: you worry, if, for example, first was added item1->ref item2(item2 itself at this time without any ref(null)) then was added item2->ref item1 and dependency will not found? At this case first chain item1->ref item2 will be continued to item1->item2->item1 automatically, because you passed all items by ref and dependency at this case will be found. When I will process item1, item2 will already have not null RefItem to item1.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov to simplify this I would say what should be the solution if these items are already in the list and I just need to validate them (all of them).